# If you don't specify a drive when compressing in 7-zip, is it normal for the zip file(s) to show up in the AppData directory?

Tags: windows-10, path, compression, 7-zip

I compressed some files the other day, and it took a while to do this, but I realized I had specified a filename but no path, and then the files I was comparessing to (split by size) ended up in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.  Is that normal?

I ran a test on them and the zip worked according to 7-zip.

Comment: Essentially, files get created in your `VirtualStore` folder when the application in question was executed with standard user access rights, so it doesn't have sufficient privileges to create them where it *wants* to make them... often places like `ProgramData` or `Windows` folders.  It sounds like those zip files are fully functional, so I would simply move them to your preferred folder location.

Comment: @Run5k Okay thank I didn't know that's what it did; I thought it would just crap out with an error letting the user know what happened.

Comment: The `VirtualStore` functionality is specifically designed to avoid that problem:  application errors or failures because of a lack of privileges.

Comment: Here is a good Stack Overflow question that helps explain things more thoroughly:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3219255  ...and here is a short post from Raymond Chen's blog that explains `UAC Virtualization`:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150902-00/?p=91681